# PHP insert statement containing numbers is wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I have got this statement:

```
   $query="INSERT INTO error_report(task_id,url_is_route, forbidden_word, google_host_fail, google_cache_fail, google_title_fail, google_element_fail, robots_noindex_nofollow, xrobots_noindex_nofollow, title_fetch_warn, h1_fail,h2_fail,h3_fail ,h1_warn ,h2_warn, h3_warn)
         VALUES (".$this->task_id.",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)";   


mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

I get this:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)' at line 2

Where does the problem lie?

**UPDATE**

```
$query="INSERT INTO error_report(task_id,url_is_route, forbidden_word, google_host_fail, google_cache_fail, google_title_fail, robots_noindex_nofollow, xrobots_noindex_nofollow, title_fetch_warn, h1_fail,h2_fail,h3_fail ,h1_warn ,h2_warn, h3_warn)
             VALUES ('".$this->task_id."','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')";
```

Now I get:

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'task_id' at row 1

Comment: I think you need to quote each entry. Like '".$this->task_id."', '0'

Comment: You forgot the quotes everywhere

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd: Can you output the value of `$query` prior to its execution and show us?

Comment: I think you've forgotten one zero for the values (if i've counted correctly, you have 16 fields and 15 values)... Oh, and what's the value of `$this->task_id`?

Comment: @Dmitry Have you actually tried with quotes? If not please first try it. This a very common problem.

Comment: I tried right now. I updated my answer.. the value of task_id is 116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use quotes
2. You are trying to update 16 columns but entering only 15 values. Correct that.

Comment: Could you please tell me of what 'type' is the column `task_id` in database and what actually is the value of `$this->task_id` ?

Comment: try to put a hardcoded value instead of `$this->task_id` in the query. If it works then may be `$this->task_id` is empty

Answer (score 2):

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'task_id' at row 1

`$this->task_id` is empty and does not contain 116 as you suspect.

Answer (score 1):

How about just setting Default Value of fields to **0** and doing:

```
$query="INSERT INTO error_report(task_id) VALUES (".$this->task_id.")";
```

Comment: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: use exactly one field name with one value for the field in your insert statement like i mentioned in answer above... and that should solve the error

Comment: I have one field that is autoincremented

Answer (score 1):

Check these

1. $this->task_id contains the value and not it is empty
2. $this->task_id   has an integer value in it or any characters. I
   think the column is int, so if it contains non integer values it throws an error